# python regex for finding ssn in text not working

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
>>> pat=re.compile('^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$')
>>> pat.findall('my sssn is 111-22-3333')
```

I am trying to catch ssn in the text. I tried the expression in pythex and it worked there but it's not wokring in python. I am new to this.

Comment: Then remove `^` and `$`. Use raw string, too: `pat=re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}')`.

Comment: "Remove anchors" is a magical phrase in such cases. I see no point in multiplying such posts where a solution is so evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `^` and the `$` anchors:

Your regex should be:

```
\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}
```

The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string, and since you have `m` in your input, `\d{3}` doesn't match.

`$` matches after the *last* character in the string, you don't really need it here unless you want nothing to appear after the last four digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
pat=re.compile('^.*?(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*$')
```

Just `group` what you want and use `.*` to catch the buffer.This will make `^$`match the whole string as opposed to what you were doing as then there were character after and before what you wanted.